# Getting invalid format response in R when using sprintf - invalid format '% he'

Tags: r

I'm trying to dynamically build an html file and one of the variables will depend on the number of files in a directory that match a pattern. Here is the code:

```
html <- '
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Sankey Plot Test</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src = "plot0.html" width = 100% height = 1000px id = "sankey" style = "border: none"></iframe>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var selector = $("#sankey");
        var delay_sec = 1;
        var num = 1, 
            len = %d;
        setInterval(function() {
          num = (num === len) ? 0 : num;
          selector.attr("src", "plot" + num + ".html");
          num++;
        }, delay_sec * 1000);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>'
n <- list.files(path = "path/to/files", pattern = "plot\\d+.html") %>% length()
html <- sprintf(html, n)
```

It's returning an error saying that the format is incorrect for my integer object, despite using `%d`. I saw a couple other questions on SO that mentioned incorrect format errors when using `%d` with `sprintf`, but none like what I'm seeing.

Any insight about what's going on would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's because it is hitting `% he` as part of `width = 100% height = 1000px` - this could have been identified by some pretty basic debugging on your behalf. Start removing your `html` text line by line until you find when the error is introduced.

Comment: You two are geniuses. Thanks! I can just use `stringr::str_interp` instead.

Comment: By the way, the XML package has functions for changing html nodes and attributes. I think it would be the safer route rather than doing string parsing stuff.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm not doing string parsing of HTML files. I'm generating my own html that houses an iframe that will cycle through `rCharts` widgets. A makeshift gif of HTML files if you will. I just need to set the length variable equal to the number of files that get generated and I don't know how to do that in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
<iframe src = "plot0.html" width = 100% height
```

Notice the %. You can escape the % with another % like this:

```
<iframe src = "plot0.html" width = 100%% height
```

When sprintf runs through the string it will output the 100% correctly.